# No wakeup after suspending

Tags: kernel, 15.04, suspend, crash

I've been getting some weird crashes after suspending. When I try to wake up, the keyboard light turns on BUT the monitor doesn't turn on and I don't think the system really recovers from suspend.

The syslog shows the following

```
Aug 28 21:01:52 arjundesktop dbus[943]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Aug 28 21:01:52 arjundesktop NetworkManager[971]: <warn>  Failed to GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.NotConnected: This interface is not connected: disconnect.
Aug 28 21:01:53 arjundesktop systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 28 21:01:53 arjundesktop systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 28 21:01:53 arjundesktop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug 28 21:01:53 arjundesktop systemd-sleep[25113]: Suspending system...
�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

The characters that aren't shown above show up as `^@` in the logs.

I don't get these crashes on my windows side. Also I've run a bunch of tests on my RAM and GPU, so I don't think it's a hardware issue. I've also investigated not waking up from "low power states" that some Haswell CPUs had, and I've disabled these power states in the bios.

- [kernel commandline](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96020841/Configs/Misc/crash-logs/arjundesktop-2016-06-08-cmdline)
- [kernel configuration](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96020841/Configs/Misc/crash-logs/arjundesktop-2016-06-08-config)
- [syslog](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96020841/Configs/Misc/crash-logs/arjundesktop-2016-08-29-syslog.log)
- [uname](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96020841/Configs/Misc/crash-logs/arjundesktop-2016-06-08-uname.log)
- [Xorg log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96020841/Configs/Misc/crash-logs/arjundesktop-2016-08-29-Xorg.log)

Comment: I had some of those extremely weird crashes where the logs just filled up with `\00\00\00\00\00\00\ ` or `@^@^@^@^@^@^@^` - not helpful for diagnosis! Eventually I "fixed" it by blacklisting a buggy kernel module (btsdio) but that's not much of a lead, I know :(

Comment: 15.04 is EOL Ubuntu hence off-topic